# Fitting the inverse Weibull distribution to data in R

Tags: r, distributions, fitting, weibull-distribution

I am trying to fit the Weibull distribution to a dataset in R. I have a dataset, "loss", as a .csv file, and use `fitdistr(loss,"invexp")`. I received the message:

> Failure infitdistr(loss, "invweibull") : unsupported distribution

How can I fit the inverse Weibull Distribution to a dataset in R?

---

Thank you! I am wonder both how to get this done in R and why I have an error when using a function fitdistr to make maximum-likelihood estimation. My error message is about function "invweibull" in R. The same problem I have for the frechet distribution. 
My dataset is the following:

> 336.893
>   2.468.001
>   572.651
>   426.581
>   501.593
>   433.167
>   708.431
>   736.761
>   1.405.323
>   2.161.790
>   492.029
>   1.429.564
>   585.885
>   563.030
>   408.345
>   4.840.762
>   308.791
>   1.201.796
>   1.463.367
>   849.336
>   510.141
>   282.088
>   648.475
>   699.729
>   849.677
>   606.299
>   380.988

I am not sure if I can simply fit a Weibull to the inverse of the observations and say then that parameters are the same for inversed weibull. I use paket "actuar" and function "invweibull" and "frechet" and become a failure unsupported distribution. Simple question is, why the estimations can not be done for this dataset and may be somebody know how is it possible to fit inverse weibull and frechet distributions in R?

Comment: Are you wondering about any of the statistical issues associated with the Weibull distribution, or fitting a distribution via maximum likelihood, or are you just wondering how to get this done in R? If the latter, this Q would be off-topic for CV (see our [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq)), but on-topic at [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). If you're interested in statistical issues, please edit to clarify, if it's just programming, flag your Q & we'll migrate it for you (*please don't cross-post, though*).

Comment: Hi @Igor and welcome to the site. If you know, can you clarify how "invexp" in your second sentence becomes "invweibull" in the error message?

Comment: It looks at first glance like the inverse Weibull is the distribution of the inverse of a Weibull distributed random variable. If this is the case, could you not simply fit a Weibull to the inverse of the observations, and obtain MLEs for the parameters from that?